# double order by in Dynamics CRM 2011 Linq query

Tags: c#, linq, dynamics-crm-2011

I'm developing a survey module for CRM 2011, where a CRM user can make a survey with multiple questions of different types and ask contacts to answer them using a dynamic web page on Azure. I have completed about 90% of it so far and just need to add a few minor changes involving data management.

The part I'm currently optimizing involves sorting my questions. I have 2 entities in CRM: surveyquestion and question. question refers to an actual question in the survey, while surveyquestion is an N-N relationship entity with a few additional fields, so we can reuse questions in different surveys. I have a field "groep" in "question" which is used to indicate whether a question should be grouped with another question on the form. I have another field,  "volgorde" in "surveyquestion", which is used to indicate the order of the questions. I wish to show all questions with the same "group" together, and then order any questions inside groups (and ungrouped questions as a separate group) by the sortorder field. So I basically need to order on 2 fields in 2 different tables, which seems to be quite tricky.

This is the code I'm currently using. I'm getting a nullreferenceexception on the join for vraaglist, which is weird because both vr.Id and ev.slfn_vraag.Id have data in the relevant rows. I don't think it's due to the orderby, because the commented code above works (but I cannot simply add ev.volgorde to my orderby because he complains about that.

```
public List<slfn_vraag> GetVragenforEnquete(Guid enGuid)
    {
        //List<slfn_vraag> vraaglist = (from vr in _oContext.slfn_vraagSet
        //                              join ev in _oContext.slfn_enquetevraagSet on vr.Id equals ev.slfn_vraag.Id
        //                              orderby vr.slfn_Groep
        //                              where ev.slfn_enquete.Id == enGuid
        //                              select vr).ToList();

        IQueryable<slfn_enquetevraag> enquetevraaglist = (from ev in _oContext.slfn_enquetevraagSet
                                       orderby ev.slfn_volgorde
                                       where ev.slfn_enquete.Id == enGuid
                                       select ev);
        List<slfn_vraag> vraaglist = (from vr in _oContext.slfn_vraagSet
                                      join ev in enquetevraaglist on vr.Id equals ev.slfn_vraag.Id
                                      orderby vr.slfn_Groep
                                      select vr).ToList();
        return vraaglist;
    }
```

The code compiles without errors, but when i run it, I get a NullReferenceException on the question query. does anyone have any ideas on how to fix this?

edit: exception details from VS2012 as requested below.

```
  System.NullReferenceException occurred
  HResult=-2147467261
  Message=De objectverwijzing is niet op een exemplaar van een object ingesteld.
  Source=Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk
  StackTrace:
       bij Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Linq.QueryProvider.TranslateJoin(QueryExpression qe, IList`1 methods, Int32& i, Projection& projection, List`1& linkLookups)
       bij Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Linq.QueryProvider.GetQueryExpression(Expression expression, Boolean& throwIfSequenceIsEmpty, Boolean& throwIfSequenceNotSingle, Projection& projection, NavigationSource& source, List`1& linkLookups)
       bij Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Linq.QueryProvider.Execute[TElement](Expression expression)
       bij Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Linq.QueryProvider.GetEnumerator[TElement](Expression expression)
       bij Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Linq.Query`1.GetEnumerator()
       bij System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
       bij System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
       bij Enquete_Webform.Data.EnqueteGenerator.GetVragenforEnquete(Guid enGuid) in e:\VS\tfs_products\MS CRM\2011\Enquete\Enquete_Webform\Enquete_Webform\Data\EnqueteGenerator.cs:regel 49
  InnerException:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading Daryl's comment about FetchXML, I've decided to convert my LINQ query to FetchXML, because this does support linked entity sorting. It now works as it should, and I get the results I need.

for completion, this is the fetchXML I ended up using:

```
<fetch version='1.0' output-format='xml-platform' mapping='logical' distinct='true'>
  <entity name='slfn_vraag'>
   <attribute name='slfn_vraagid' />
   <attribute name='slfn_vraag' />
   <attribute name='slfn_typevraag' />
   <attribute name='slfn_groep' />
   <order attribute='slfn_groep' descending='false' />
   <link-entity name='slfn_enquetevraag' from='slfn_vraag' to='slfn_vraagid' alias='aa'>
       <attribute name='slfn_volgorde'/>
       <order attribute='slfn_volgorde' descending='false' />
       <filter type='and'>
           <condition attribute='slfn_enquete' operator='eq' value='" + enGuid+@"' />
       </filter>
   </link-entity>
  </entity>
</fetch>
```

As an aside, None of the fields could be empty, because they were all primary and foreign keys in CRM, linking to other entities.

Comment: Why can't a foreign key be null?

Comment: because I create my surveys using a dialog process, which makes sure that all fields are filled with a valid key. you'll never have an enquetevraag where the vraag is null, because enquetevragen are generated along with vragen. so it's not exactly becase it's a foreign key, but because the design means that it cannot be null.

Comment: ah, the front end is forcing it, but there is nothing in the database enforcing it.

Answer (score 1):

[Enumerable.OrderBy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534966.aspx) and [Enumerable.ThenBy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534743.aspx) applied to the final `vraaglist`, might offer a solution to your case.

Comment: This does not work, because OrderBy and ThenBy require the field to sort on to be part of the selected table. Because 1 of my fields is not from the selected table, it does not work.

Comment: As a followup: I've tried adding my "OrderBy" both before and after the ToList(), and even just removing all orderby statements, and neither of the 3 options give a different result.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you have an ev.slfn_vraag that is null.  Try adding a where statement to exclude those that have a null value

```
List<slfn_vraag> vraaglist = (from vr in _oContext.slfn_vraagSet
                              join ev in enquetevraaglist on vr.Id equals ev.slfn_vraag.Id
                              where ev.slfn_vragg.Id != null
                              orderby vr.slfn_Groep
                              select vr).ToList();
```

You could also have the null in the first statement as well:

```
var enquetevraaglist = (from ev in _oContext.slfn_enquetevraagSet
                        orderby ev.slfn_volgorde
                        where ev.slfn_enquete != null && ev.slfn_enquete.Id == enGuid
                        select ev)
```

I've created an extension method on the Entity Reference class that allows for nulls without erroring.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Returns the Id of the entity reference or Guid.Empty if it is null"
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="entity"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static Guid GetIdOrDefault(this EntityReference entity)
    {
        if (entity == null)
        {
            return Guid.Empty;
        }
        else
        {
            return entity.Id;
        }
    }
```

And as far as your question about sorting, CRM doesn't support sorting by a linked field, just keep that in mind.

Comment: I have added these != null checks, and they didn't solve the issue. as for the sorting question, I wanted to dodge that bullet by first sorting the enquetevragen and then using the sorted IQueryable<enquetevragen> to get the right questions, and then sort the vragenlist. or can I not combine LINQ queries in this fashion?

Comment: @nzall as far as your null error goes, there are only 3 possibilities for the cause.  _oContext is null, slfn_enquete is null or slfn_vraag.    is null.  If you have any plugins on the read, they could potentially be throwing the exception as well, but from the stack trace, I'm guessing that's not the problem.

Comment: @nzall as far as the sorting goes, you may have to change your IQueryable into a list.  That way CRM performs 2 queries, rather than just 1 at a time.

Comment: Does CRM not support linked field sorting AT ALL, or would it be possible to use a QueryExpression to sort using a linked field? Or by FetchXML? Or is it just not supported at all?

Comment: @nzall QueryExpressions don't support sorting on a Linked Entity, and LINQ uses Query Expressions under the covers, so it doesn't support it either.  Fetch XML does support it however: http://nishantrana.wordpress.com/2012/04/27/sorting-on-link-entitys-attribute-in-fetch-xml-crm-2011/